# Who provides the best and/or most affordable VPS hosting for FreeBSD guests?

Tags: vps, freebsd

I've seen plenty of recommendations for Linux VPS hosting, but not as much for FreeBSD. Who's the Linode/Slicehost of the BSD world? As an added bonus, who provides cheap but serviceable BSD hosting?

Comment: I've had nothing but great experience with ARP Networks  (http://arpnetworks.com).  Clued people, very customer focused, native IPv6, definitely happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First-hand recommendation: Rootbsd.net. They are part of a larger Linux hosting house, but their FreeBSD expertise is quite high. I have had a few in-depth conversations with tech support, and always come away impressed.

Comment: I have also had good luck with Rootbsd.net

Answer (score 1):

[Csoft.net](http://www.csoft.net/) - Reliable, affordable, knowledgeable.

Maybe not *the cheapest*, but you usually get what you pay for.

Comment: Is that actually VPS hosting? Most of the info on the site seemed more like shared (probably using jails) hosting.

Comment: It depends on the plan you get. They have everything from VirtualHost type plans, to VPS, to full Private Servers. The "Advanced" and "Corporate" plans are VPS (It does actually mention that in the details of the plans).

Answer (score 0):

While not providing a FreeBSD solution directly, the guys at http://prgmr.com let you install it. They have instructions on how to install NetBSD, and you can try adapt them for FreeBSD. They use xen, so only 8.0 i386 for the moment.

Comment: From PRGMR's own wiki "Xen support is in its infancy, but the stuff in 8-CURRENT only works on Xen hypervisor version 3.2 and above, so this should work with the newer prgmr.com servers running Xen 3.3, however, I don't know of anyone successfully working on it."